# How to pass the return value of a function as a property to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How is it possible to pass the return value of a function to a property of a react component? For the following example a *TypeError: props.columns is undefined* is thrown.

```
        <ReactDataGrid
          columns={this.props.data['head'] && this.props.data['head']['vars'].map(function(heading) {
                return {key: heading, name: heading, editable : true}
          })}
        rowGetter={this.rowGetter} />
```

Comment: could you post what  `this.props.data['head']` and `this.props.data['head']['vars']` contains

Comment: Example - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46531/

Comment: this.props.data['head'] contains:
{
 "vars": [
  "name",
  "provider",
  "consumer",
  "lifeCyclePhase",
  "protocol",
  "message",
  "interfaceConsumerContact"
 ]
}
but only after a few seconds because it is aysnc

Comment: Why provide a solution in comments rather than in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put the null check outside of the property:

```
      if (this.props.data['head']) {
        return (
          <ReactDataGrid
          columns={this.props.data['head']['vars'].map(function(heading) {
              return {key: heading, name: heading, editable : true}
          })}
          rowGetter={this.rowGetter} />
        )
      } else {
        return (<span>Loading</span>)
      }
```

Comment: Check out @alexander-t jsFiddle, he essentially does the same thing but instead of wrapping the entire `ReactDataGrid` component in an if-statement, you just store the result in a variable.

Comment: The problem with that is, that the variable than can be null and ReactDataGrid does not like that.